# Lost luggage in Amsterdam Schiphol Airport with Vueling Airlines

Tags: compensation, ams, lost-luggage

I just had a bad experience today. This is my first trip to Europe with my parents and we arrived from Roma to Amsterdam this morning using Vueling Airlines.

After I arrived at the luggage hall we picked up the luggage for my parents, but mine was lost. I asked the Airport Customer Service and they recommended me to Airfrov partner.
After that I went to the Airfrov Partner for the lost and found luggage and made a report. I asked them if is it usual that tourists lose baggage here? They said no, but usually while their lost their baggage someone who take the luggage will bring it to the airport.

The thing is inside my luggage is a wallet and I have my important documents, driving license, ID Card, money and everything in there. Fortunately my passport was in my small pocket.

May I know if this is true? Has somebody else ever lost their luggage?

What is the amount that the airline, Vueling, will refund to us?

Comment: Never place your passport, ID card, or money in hold luggage. Always keep these things in your possession.

Comment: You might be able to get a status update on locating your bag here https://www.vueling.com/en/vueling-services/more-vueling-services/damaged-and-delayed-baggage/status-of-delayed-luggage

Comment: Thank you all for your comment and suggestions. Actually i'm really2 dissapointed with the Vueling Airlines Services. They just throw away me to the airport departments lost and found to create the report. Until now there isn't any reply from the Airport lost and found department. I have asked the Airport why the security is very loss? They should check the tag baggage of everyone luggae out of the airport. Otherwise everyone will be happen like me.

Comment: Most likely it is not the airline but either airport which is responsible for losing your luggage. Most luggage not on the flight will come with the next plane. And is misplaced in the arrival airport, it can be found any moment. Make sure lost and found has your holiday and home address, so they can get your bag to you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry this happened to you. Luggage does get lost, and it usually gets found. Within Europe, about [8 bags per thousand are mishandled](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travel-truths/What-happens-to-lost-luggage/), and the Association of European Airlines statistics are that 85% of bags reported as lost are returned to their owners within 48 hours. So there's a good chance your bag was just misplaced, and will be returned to you soon. However, some bags are lost or stolen permanently, about 7% of those mishandled worldwide (in other words, 7% of bags reported as missing are never found).

If your bag is lost permanently, [you're entitled to compensation](https://www.vueling.com/en/customer-services/conditions-of-carriage#luggage), though proving what was lost can be difficult. If you have travel insurance, contact your insurance company immediately, as coverage for delayed and lost bags is usually part of your policy.

It's obviously too late for this now, but never check in any valuable items, money, medication, keys, electronics, etc... If you can avoid it, don't check anything essential to your trip or anything with sentimental value. I always like to travel with the assumption that my bags could be delayed and keep everything I need immediately, including a quick change of clothes, with me in a small carry-on bag. Your wallet is certainly something you want to keep with you on board. There are plenty of shops that will sell you clothes in Amsterdam, but none that will replace your ID and credit cards.

Sometimes people do take the wrong bag at the baggage claim. You can decorate your bag to make it more distinctive, to reduce the likelihood of this happening, but most people will return the bag if this happens (after all, they want their own bag instead).

Comment: 7% worldwide of the bags that are 'mishandled', presumably?

Comment: @MastaBaba Yes, thank you. 7% of all checked bags aren't permanently lost.

Comment: @MastaBaba no, 7% of the bags that are lost are never found.

Comment: Add prescription medications to the carry-on items. It can take time to get a prescription reissued and filled.

Comment: Add contact lenses too